# find bad word using strpos from string

Tags: php

I have following php code to find bad word in a string.

It stop on first bad word found and return true.

The bad words are provided as comma separated list that is converted to array.

```
$paragraph = "We have fur to sell";
$badWords = "sis, fur";
$badWordsArray = explode(",", $badWords);

function strpos_arr($string, $array, $offset=0) { // Find array values in string
    foreach($array as $query) {
        if(strpos($string, $query, $offset) !== false) return true; // stop on first true result for efficiency
    }
    return false;
}

strpos_arr($paragraph, $badWordsArray);
```

The issue is it also returns true if bad word provided is a part of another word.

I prefer using **strpos**.
Please also suggest if there is any more efficient way to find bad words.

Comment: Try using regex

Comment: I don't know how to use regex with strpos.

Comment: You can also explode the input string. `$paragraphArray = explode(" ", $paragraph);` and then use in_array function. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

`foreach ($paragraphArray as $pgItem) {
    if (in_array($pgItem, $badWordsArray)) { //is a bad word} else {//not bad}}`

Comment: @ Janno, It do not work if bad word is the 1st word in string.

Comment: @Syed, take a look at my answer which uses regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, with reqular expression:

```
$paragraph = "We have fur to sell";
$badWords = "sis, fur";
$badWordsArray = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $badWords, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($badWordsArray);

function searchBadWords($string, $array, $offset=0) { // Find array values in string
    foreach ($array as $query) {
        if (preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote($query, '/') . '\b/i', $string)) return true; // stop on first true result for efficiency
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(searchBadWords($paragraph, $badWordsArray));
```

**Explanation:**

First. We want to correctly split our `$badWords` string:

```
$badWordsArray = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $badWords, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This way we will correctly split strings like `"sis, fur"` and `"sis , fur"` and even `"sis ,   , fur"` to an `array('sis', 'fur')`.

Then we are performing regexp-search of exact word using `\b` meta-character. Which means `word-boundary` in terms of regular expression, that is position **between** a *word-characted* and a *non-word-character*.

Comment: thanks @spirit, do you think `preg_match` is more efficient then `strpos` in this situation.

Comment: if you need to search for exact word - yes. `strpos` is faster, but it requires additional code to achive exact search.

Comment: alternatively, you can `preg_split()` your `$paragraph` and use `in_array()` =)

Comment: I am about to accept your answer, please up vote my question and make `preg_match` **case insensitive**.

Answer (score 0):

Just include spaces in your search string.

```
$paragraph = "We have fur to sell";
$badWords = "sis, fur";
$badWordsArray = explode(",", $badWords);

function strpos_arr($string, $array, $offset=0) { // Find array values in string

$string = " ".$string." ";

foreach($array as $query) {
    $query = " ".$query." ";
    if(strpos($string, $query, $offset) !== false) return true; // stop on first true result for efficiency
}
return false;
}

strpos_arr($paragraph, $badWordsArray);
```

Comment: thanks for reply,  It do not work if bad word is the 1st or last word in string.

Comment: Did you test the new code ? (it has a new line : `$string = " ".$string." ";`)